# Overwriting a single line in original file in shell

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file like this-

```
Asia
Europe
Africa
```

I want to search for word Europe and insert '#' in front of it which should appear like this-

```
Asia
#Europe
Africa
```

I tried:

```
sed -e 's/"Europe"/"#Europe"/g' $file
```

Also:

```
sed -r 's/"Europe"/"#Europe"/g' $file > $tmp`
mv $tmp $file
```

But it is not overwriting that particular line only,infact updating he file with a single line only like this:

```
#Europe
```

Comment: I have edited my initial answer (now using the `-i` option) in order to achieve the in-place file modification.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/^Europe/#&/' file
```